# File Body Search

Tags: php, file, search

Can anyone recommend a good tool for searching though the body of files (office, powerpoint ect). It needs to be integrated as part of a PHP site. Alternatively, any server side applications that could be used for creating indexes of the search terms.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Zend_Lucene](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html). It supports parsing of Word, Powerpoint and Excel (2007) documents.

Answer (score 0):

I know how to get the contents of the body, but not the search part. Here is the function I use:

```
function body($file) {
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);
    $parts = explode("<body>", $contents);
    $parts = explode("</body>", $parts[1]);
    return $parts[0];
}
```

Of course, this only works if there aren't any attributes on the body tag.